# Event Tracking in Google Analytics for a Music Site

Tags: javascript, events, analytics, tracking

Hi I recently added universal google analytics event tracking for song downloads on my music site but for some reason the individual events aren't appearing under events in GA. Did I implement the tracking incorrectly?

Here is the site:

http://www.Dreamlouise.com/

Here is an example of the tracking I implemented:DOWNLOAD FULL ALBUM ( NORMAL / HI-RES)

Comment: I am getting a error on the page in my chrome console, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (index):423. That will probably stop javascript further down the page from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the error console, you have an unexpected token right in the middle of your google analytics code.

```
...
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');</p>
...
```

It doesn't like the `</p>` and I'm not sure why you would have that tag in the middle of a script on the page.  Try removing the two `<p>` tags throughout the `<script>`

Comment: Hey I went ahead and fixed it but I'm still not seeing it in GA? Do you think there's a lag or a delay for when it shows up in GA?